# Downloading Solrj source file

Tags: apache, download, solr, solrj

Can anyone guide me to where I can download that latest SolrJ release source files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solrj is bundled with Solr, so if you download the Solr Source package you will find the Solrj source code included in it.

https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/3.2.0/apache-solr-3.2.0-src.tgz

It's located in the directory

```
solr/src/sorlj
```

Comment: i need a class called  "MultiThreadedHttpSolrServer"  Can you help me where it is present

Comment: Hmm. It seems to be not included in the source (yet). But it seems to be available via a patch in their Jira system: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-457. But I don't know. It looks pretty old (2008).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the latest stable release than it is exactly like @Daniel said.
If you want the latest source files you can find the in the Subversion repository of Apache.

They latest source (not a stable release) can be viewed here [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/src/solrj/) or checked out from [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/)

You can check the stability of this code by looking at the hudson build server and seeing the health of the latest build.

Back when I was trying to do better sharding support for Solr I worked a lot with the nightly builds (if you need regular bug fixes). You can get the nightly build from the links I added below it will be in the form of a jar and can be used the same way you use the stable release, but again be advised you need to look at the build health to see that it is worth the risk.

- Nightly builds for Solr3.3 - [jar](https://builds.apache.org/job/Solr-3.x/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/artifacts/), [status](https://builds.apache.org/job/Solr-3.x/lastSuccessfulBuild/)
- Nightly builds for Solr4 - [jar](https://builds.apache.org/job/Solr-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/artifacts/), [status](https://builds.apache.org/job/Solr-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/)

Also if you really need to be on top of what's going on in the code but don't want a completely unstable release, you can wait for a release candidate and download it. If you want to know when release candidates are available the best way is to subscribe to the "lucene-dev" mailing list and look for voting on a release candidate. [example](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-dev/201106.mbox/browser)

Tell me if you need more information